# VB2010 How to assign value to a variable in lostfocus?

Tags: vb.net, casting

I want to assign a string value to a variable in the DataGridView LostFocus event. I found that I can't just do `variable = "string value`, it will give me the "Unable to cast object of type ‘system.eventargs’ to type ‘system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs’" error.

The function created by double-clicking on the datagridview is:

```
Private Sub DataGridViewInvoice_LostFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewInvoice.LostFocus
```

Thanks,
Raymond

Comment: Where is the failing code? The event in which you try to assign a variabile has nothing to do with the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the wrong parameters for the .LostFocus event.

```
Dim s As String = ""
Sub DataGridView1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.LostFocus
    s = "Hello"
    MsgBox(s)
End Sub
```

Also, maybe you should consider the .Leave event instead, as suggested in the remarks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Andrew,thanks for the link. I don't encounter any issue after using the Leave event.